# Truncate text in floated box and show it entirely when hovering

Tags: css, css-float

I have following html:

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-left">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box-right">
    <button>Resource View</button>
    <button>Employee View</button>
    <button>Regular View</button>
  </div> 
</div>
```

---

Here's how it looks by default:

[image]

How it looks when hovering the text (we show full text length):

[image]

---

Some more informations:

- I'm using text-ellipsis to truncate text ([see here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/))
- When text is hovered, we're using `:hover` selector to set `position:absolute` to text paragraph
- We don't know in advance the width of `.box-right`, neither the width of `.box-left`
- `.box` width equals window's width (so it's variable)

---

Actually, I have this example working with CSS and Javascript, the javascript consists of setting `.box-left p`'s element width on page load, using:

```
$('.box-left p').css('width', $('.box').innerWidth() - $('.box-right').outerWidth())
```

---

Question:

- I'm wondering if there's a CSS only solution? I've tried with `display: table-cell` without success.

What I want to do:

- Truncate text of `.box-left` to have buttons and text on one line
- When hovering text, show it's full length

Comment: "We don't know in advance the width..." - why not?  Can't we use percentages?

Comment: On hover do you want to hide all the box right content or only the part that the left text covers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this:

Notice that I have't set a width on the box. It will work no matter what the width of the box is.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/rC392/2/)**

### Markup:

```
<div class="box">
   <div class="box-right">
        <button>Resource View</button>
        <button>Employee View</button>
        <button>Regular View</button>
  </div>
  <div class="box-left">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div> 
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.box
{
  border:1px solid green; 
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.box-left p
{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block; 
    min-height: 30px;
}
.box-left p:hover
{
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
}
.box-right
{
    float: right; 
    display: inline-block; 
}
.box-right button
{
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

Comment: I think you should add `width:100%` to `.box-left p:hover` and then we're golden (as it will cover all the buttons at any width) :)

Comment: @gvee I don't know what the OP needs regarding this. (Look at the question I asked in the comments on the question)

Comment: @Daneild I know what you mean, but it looks a bit pants if half the button is cut off.. Perhaps a nice `box-shadow` on the right hand side to at least feather the edges? :P

Comment: it's also a shame that we have to alter the HTML flow, otherwise we could style the `box-right` when hovering over `box-left`. Damn CSS not allowing to select previous siblings

Answer (score 2):

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dp6Xs/**

### CSS

```
.box {
    width: 600px;
    height: 2em;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.box > div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}

.box-left {
    left: 0;
    width: 250px;
}

.box-left > p {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.box-right {
    right: 0;
    width: 350px;
}

.box-left:hover {
    width: 100%;
}

.box-left:hover + .box-right {
    display: none;
}
```

The idea is that when we hover on `.box-left` we increase the width to 100% of the parent and we hide it's sibling `.box-right`.

Comment: The tricky part is `.box` width is variable. It can be 600px or any other value.